Ubuntu overlayfs problem on keeping userdata
I don't want to use overlayroot because it will restore my /home directory, which contains user data. I want to preserve the rootfs after a reboot, except for /home, mmcblk0p9  is where my rootfs at
ubuntu@mtk-genio:/$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0          7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1          7:1    0  59.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/2019
loop2          7:2    0  59.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/2321
loop3          7:3    0  69.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1383
loop4          7:4    0  69.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1438
loop5          7:5    0 246.5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4423
loop6          7:6    0 246.5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4453
loop7          7:7    0   334M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/145
loop8          7:8    0 475.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/143
loop9          7:9    0 483.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/178
loop10         7:10   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop11         7:11   0  11.7M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/963
loop12         7:12   0  35.5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20298
loop13         7:13   0  33.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21761
loop14         7:14   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/159
loop15         7:15   0   416K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/85
mmcblk0      179:0    0  59.2G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0     4M  0 part
├─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0     4M  0 part
├─mmcblk0p3  179:3    0    32M  0 part
├─mmcblk0p4  179:4    0    32M  0 part
├─mmcblk0p5  179:5    0   512K  0 part
├─mmcblk0p6  179:6    0     1M  0 part
├─mmcblk0p7  179:7    0    32M  0 part
├─mmcblk0p8  259:0    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
└─mmcblk0p9  259:1    0  58.6G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                       /


/dev/mmcblk0p9 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro)

So I want to add OverlayFS to my Ubuntu to protect my rootfs.
I am currently trying the following steps:
1.Prepare Directories for OverlayFS
sudo chmod 755 /mnt/overlay/upper /mnt/overlay/work /merged

sudo mkdir -p /mnt/overlay/upper
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/overlay/work
sudo mkdir -p /merged

2.Configure fstab
LABEL=writable  /       ext4    discard,errors=remount-ro       0 1
    overlay /merged overlay lowerdir=/,upperdir=/mnt/overlay/upper,workdir=/mnt/overlay/work 0 0

3.Point User Interface to /merged
sudo mkdir -p /merged/home/username
sudo chown -R username:username /merged/home/username

After rebooting, when I add a file named "123" to /merged/home/ubuntu/desktop, the file also appears in /mnt/overlay/upper/home/ubuntu/desktop.
It seems the behavior is correct.
Next, I want my rootfs to be read-only. I tried modifying the fstab entry for the root partition like this:
LABEL=writable /       ext4    discard,errors=remount-ro,ro 0 1

However, this prevents my system from entering GNOME and stuck on maintenance mode.
Could you please advise on how to correctly make the rootfs read-only or it is impossible since my /home is under rootfs?
